# Webpack 2: Provide entry name to imported sass modules as variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have two entries; `bundle-a.js` and `bundle-b.js`.

Both of these entry bundles import `component.scss`.

I would like to prepend `component.scss` module with `$bundle: '{entry-name}';` e.g. `$bundle: 'bundle-b';`

Is this possible? I assume loaders or plugins but have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Banner Plugin?

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/

It doesn't solve your issue entirely, but might give you a good head start.